# How to create a PHP function to return a product category description - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, return, woocommerce

I'm newby in php, and I need some help.

I'm using wp al export to export data as product title, category, excerpt, etc...

They have an option to export the produtc_category title, but not the product category description.

They have an option to export the category value returned by a PHP function, and the value I have to return is the product category description.

[Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vlmugn7jzw6n82e/allexport.png?dl=0)

I have to create a PHP function to get that value and I'm getting crazy to achieve that.

I found a post  that explains how to [show the product category description in the product category page](http://www.haloseeker.com/how-to-display-woocommerce-product-category-description/)

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'custom_add_product_description', 12);
function custom_add_product_description ($category) {
$cat_id        =    $category->term_id;
$prod_term    =    get_term($cat_id,'product_cat');
$description=    $prod_term->description;
echo '<div>'.$description.'</div>';
}
```

The thing is that I don't want to display the product category description in my product category page. I just want to create a function to return the description when it is called.

Please HELP!!!!! :)

Comment: If you want to return a value then just return the value instead of echoing it. `return $description`

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work.. :(

Comment: FYI Category description will be same for perticular category page :)

Comment: so category description after product title will be same for perticular category page

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be you get some solution:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'my_add_cat_description', 9);
function my_add_cat_description () {
/*  if(!is_shop()){*/  //check whether execute shop page?
    global $product;

    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo $product_cat_id = $term->description;
    break;
}

echo '<div class="shop_cat_desc">testing</div>';
/*}*/
}
```

visit link to check condition: [LINK](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/)